# Is there an abbreviation for "skill"?

Tags: abbreviations

Is there an abbreviation for "skill"?
I know the s-k-i-l-l is not a long word but still want to know whether there's some extreme expression.

Comment: No.  But there is a shorthand for "all the skills and abilities you have (or that you need to have so as to be able to do [X]:   **skill set**

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Got it, so kind of you:)

Answer (score 1):

Skill, as you mentioned is too short to be abbreviated and no abbreviations will make sense for the word. However, I've seen in many places, where an image that represents skills is used to convey the same meaning.
[image: Skill]

Comment: This seems like an odd image to represent "skill"...I would sooner associate this with "settings" or "options" or something along those lines. Where have you seen this to mean skill?

Comment: Why don't you try Googling images for "skills".

Comment: Well I took your advice and that icon literally appears nowhere. Why don't you try googling images for "settings"?

Comment: Please commit yourself to a little more research before you blatantly criticize an answer. [This is the link to Google images for the search "Skills icon"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=skills&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU4r3K2-zLAhUNCo4KHVtMB0gQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=skills+icon)

Comment: My criticism was meant to be constructive. You didn't actually answer my question - where have you actually seen that icon outside of a Google search? All I'm saying is that the image of gears is much more commonly used to represent "settings" than "skills" and I think most people would agree.